Creating DEM from LiDAR on ArcGIS Pro
I'm currently trying to create a DEM out of LiDAR data. According to various tutorials, you have to create pyramids on the .las file and then perform a ground classification. The problem is that the ground classification tool on ArcGIS Pro is performed with no errors, but the file remains unchanged. Normally, the ground points should turn brown and the rest gray, which is not the case. I was wondering if I can filter the file to only have the ground points and if the result would be the same as with the ground classification once rasterized.

Please [Edit] the Question to provide more details about the exact command and its output (the command history can capture this as ASCII text to paste into the body).

Filter for ground points under 'LAS Dataset Layer', 'Filters', 'LAS Points', 'Ground'?

